# How can I ignore throwing error when I initialize a negative number to a unsigned column?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my query:

```
UPDATE users SET events = events - 1 WHERE id = 10
```

this query only works when the current value of `events` column is `1` or more. Otherwise it throws this:

> #1690 - BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(`dbname`.`users`.`events` - 1)'

How can I fix this problem? I want to keep `0` value as `events` column's value instead of throwing an error.

Noted that `events` column is `int(11) unsigned`.

Comment: `WHERE id = 10 AND events >= 1`?

Answer (score 0):

How about a `where` clause?

```
UPDATE users
    SET events = events - 1
    WHERE id = 10 AND events > 0;
```

You wouldn't want negative events anyway.